# LAMP: Recommended Directory and File Permissions

Tags: linux, security, lamp

My project resides in a shared Linux hosting server. The hosting provider, of course, has already set up the necessary directory and file ownerships relative to other server users. My concern for now is how to setup permissions within my domain so my users can have read access to the files and folders they should have and still let my scripts retain read/write access to it.

Question: What would be the recommended permissions on:

1. Public files and folders (read only?)
2. Files where uploaded files from forms are stored
3. Files and folders where GD and cache files are being written into
4. Folders where my server-side scripts are stored (I used mainly PHP)
5. My WWW root folder (where `index.php` resides)

Comment: When you say 'my users' are you referring to other people who have access to the server's file system, or users accessing your website?

Comment: oh sorry. i'm referring to the end-users of the website accessing contents mainly via browsers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a perfect example of where you need the Principle of Least Privilege.  Allow ReadOnly to the webserver's user for RO content, allow writing only to a directory/files that absolutely need to be written.  Explicitly deny access to things you don't want people to read (config files, htaccess, anything with paths/ip addresses/passwords), don't allow any extra processing if you're not using it (CGI executables, Server Side Includes).

The best way to do it is to start with deny everything and slowly open thing up as you go.  First try serving static content, see what is the minimal amount of Apache directives/modules and filesystem ownerships and permissions to get it working.  Then try some RO PHP scripts.  Then try some RW PHP scripts.  Then DB connectivity,  and so on, you get the idea... It's a very tedious processes, and you want to plan ahead the sort of things you want to test; I tend to write long  scripts with wget commands trying to do both good and bad things to the server.  Make one change, restart, rerun the script, see what changes from the last time.  Observe-modify-analyze, until you cant stand looking at it anymore ;)

Comment: So I'll start with 664 permission on all directories then? I'm sorry Im just starting in Linux.

Comment: I'd rather start with much more restrictive (apache:apache,400), but If you're completely new to this, starting from a permissive 664 would probably be easier for you.  The major point here should be that if you're having problems with permissions, you really should not be in charge of hardening an internet-facing website.  Properly assigning ownerships, permissions, and umasks can be tricky even for a veteran.